# How Static allocation in spark works?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know how it wprks when you specify number of executors and cores in spark submit. but how does it assigns executors statically when I don't specify the number of executors. Does it have a specific executor number ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the default values of the spark.executor.instances for YARN mode:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

spark.executor.instances: Default value is 2

`The number of executors for static allocation. With spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled, the initial set of executors will be at least this large.`